# Binding eval with context

Tags: javascript, binding, eval

I'm trying to use eval in HTMLElement's context to mimic event attributes (like onclick) in data attributes with proper context.

Let's have `x={}`, then this code doesn't work

```
fx = eval.bind(x);
fx("console.log(this)"); // Window, expected Object
```

...but this one does:

```
fn = (function(_){eval(_)}).bind(x);
fn("console.log(this)"); // Object, as expected
```

Can you explain the differences?

Comment: may be that becous of In the global execution context (outside of any function), "this" always refers to the global object (window).

Comment: @WillBlack I understand that `eval`'s argument is evaluated in the context where it is called. I do not understand why binding other context (`eval.bind`) has no effect. `fn.bind(x)` should bind the context (this) `x` to `fn`. Except for `eval`.